# php curl download remote image

Tags: php, curl

I have a authorization to use an image from partiner website to qork on my own.

So I try download the image from they `src`, with curl:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://imgs.kenlo.io/VWRCUkQ2Tnp3d1BJRDBJVe1szkhnWr9UfpZS9bJDwnbk9Kawbnev1nxMNm9yHFhIP-MQkSx9WYNv23hLzO9I+z0StvcEfe6ggnXCx6+I286Lt3WU3rLdkIrG9OL9c8jv4qJ6-arDAl+tq417XfgQOV8gR8xCbkPFTqGKY2BopgOv92LEFusYUk1n0h8jsUZu6AHoQYT1sl0yxA2UXuyB8nTQCaC5XwwWUawNEtEw7ldR7AL0SVpntREFocalqyCZPuL1JoCihipUBAow-56-X7-hkZaPK5RkVqk2dXwP61MDUbcUm+6GWehj7QEYoKGTVkPBwEKa07d3JM+tW4tMnqVWwgaVGrAa6B-pxYyVhaWpZk7UOk5Bqu-A7fCxS+CyRv7jOCq8j4pBrN-bbYYZKprkVzEVTw==.jpg';
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.ricimoveis.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $resource_ext_img_destaque = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close($ch);
    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/magickscp/dev-misc/fdp12.jpg', $resource_ext_img_destaque);
```

The partiner use a regional platform that store images on `imgs.kenlo.io` server, apparently that server uses some security tricks to block this operation.

I note somethings like:

The `url` to img probably have a redirect becouse when i see the requests sometimes a i have '200' or '301'.

So the doubt is, what things i need to evaluate on the response header, to make this work?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: not bring the img... i work in other solution, but i gona edit that question to understand this behavior